# (How) should I describe the company within my bachelor's thesis?

Tags: thesis, bachelor

I'm writing my computer science bachelor's thesis in a company. The thesis is about optimizing one of their software products. Obviously I will need to describe the software in the thesis, but what about the company itself?

Is it sufficient to name the company and give a short description of what they're about, or should I go into more detail like e.g. the history of the company?

(I'm new here, so if this question isn't a good fit, feel free to let me know :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or should I go into more detail like e.g. the history of the company?

No, in general, there's no need for that: your thesis is not a company's brochure. Provide enough information to present the context of your thesis, but don't add too much unnecessary details.

Anyway, I suggest you to discuss this also with your university supervisor: they surely know what is the policy or the tradition about this in the university, and they can act as buffer between possible company's requests and university requirements.